# Restart Android application using shell script

Tags: android, shell, scripting

I'm trying to restart an application (*com.android.snapchat*) through `am` command.

My code to start the application is

```
am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.MAIN \
                  -n com.android.snapchat/.MainActivity
```

The above starts the snapchat application. However, my program flow is to achieve this:

```
while true
if(snapchat is running)
then
    restart snapchat
    ...
else
    start snapchat
    ....
```

How can I do this using `am` command itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For restarting the app first run

```
am force-stop com.android.snapchat
```

and then start it again with the command you've been using.